# Can google be used as your Authentication / Authorization provider?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

In the past I have used Auth0 and Identity Server as my authentication / authorization providers. Basically we built a .netcore microservice around them and used that for creating / maintaining / validating JWT bearer tokens.

Can google be used to the same effect or is it simply meant for logging into an application?

Comment: Check out https://developers.google.com/identity/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can google be used to the same effect or is it simply meant for
>   logging into an application?

**The quick answer to your question is YES, you can use Google for authentication.**

When you look at using Google for authentication and authorization, you are talking about two different things. Google also has different types of services to serve different purposes. The key is to decide who you want to authenticate. Anyone on the Internet, or only those that are part of your company (domain name)?

If you are comfortable with Auth0, you will be right at home with Google OAuth.
 OAuth 2.0 is a standard, which means most vendors implement the same services, same interfaces, same everything.

**Google Accounts**

This is the service what most people think of. Anyone can create a Google Account and these accounts use the email address form `someone@gmail.com`. You can use this service to authenticate to your own services. You provide authorization yourself thru your own mechanisms. Let's say that you have a chat application and only those that have a Google Account can join. You don't care who. When the user authenticates with Google, they receive a series of tokens (Access Token, Refresh Token, Identity Token). You can use the Identity Token to know who the person is (their email addresses).

Now if you want to only allow certain people, you would maintain a database of "authorized" individuals and grant permissions based upon their identity.

Google Accounts is very easy to implement providing you understand OAuth 2.0. There are numerous code examples on the Internet supporting just about any language server-side. Client-side is always performed in a web browser.

**Google G Suite / Google Identity Server**

If your goal is to only support members in your own company via a domain name, use Google G Suite (paid) or Google Identity Server (free). Everything that I mentioned above is the same except you create email addresses for your members in the form `someone@mydomain.com`.

Thousands (millions) of companies use Google for authentication. Billion+ consumers have a Google Account.

**Authorization**

You will notice that I am not talking about Google being used for Authorization. Google does not have an infrastructure for you to program (store details on) what can be authorized. The types of services and permission that your own applications have are boundless. You do authorization yourself, for example storing details about user's permissions in a database.

The exceptions are Google Cloud which has an extensive authorization system built supporting IAM (Identity and Access Management) for Google Cloud Services and other Google services such as Gmail, Drive, Sheets, etc. which use OAuth Scopes and Access Tokens to manage authorization.